# Integration $1/e^{(2-3x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, substitution

One question in integration is to integrate $1/e^{(2-3x)} dx$
the provided answer is to let $e^{-(2-3x)}   = e^{(3x-2)}$  then integrate it to be 
$1/3 e^{3x-2}$
the question is why we can't use $u = (2-3x)$ then $du= -3$
so it should be $-1/3 (1/u) du   = -1/3 \ln|u| $ instead of the provided answer

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've edited it to include MathJax format, however, you might want to double check.

Comment: Set $e^{2-3x}=u\implies?$

Comment: Your argument is very badly stated.  If $u=2-3x$ it is not true that $du=-3,$ it is $du=-3dx$.  It is also not true that $-1/3 (1/u) du   = -1/3 \ln|u|$.  You intended an integral sign on the left which is not there and you need a constant on the right.  Please be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly obtain the correct result using $u = 2-3x$ and $du = -3dx$, however you would need to use two substitutions, and you substituted the quantity back into the integral incorrectly.

Upon substitution, you would get $$\int\frac1{e^{2-3x}}dx \to \int\frac{-1}{3e^u}du = -\frac{1}{3}\int e^{-u}du$$

Then, you would need to substitute $v = -u$ and $dv = -du$ to get
$$\frac1{3}\int e^v dv = \frac13e^v + C = \frac13e^{-u} + C = \frac13e^{3x-2} + C$$

As you can see, this still gives you the desired result, but it was a far more roundabout way to do it. Of course, $\int e^{-u} du$ is a fairly trivial integral to do in your head, so most people don't need to do a second level of substitution, but behind the scenes, that is what's happening.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Because your denominator is $e^u$, not $u$, so you can't integrate to $\ln |u|$

Comment: Thank you, i didn't notice the e ^u not u